# Does hillbilly slang fall under a type of English language and if not, what is it called?

Tags: dialects, southern-white-vernacular-english

Does hillbilly slang (for lack of better words) fall under a type of English language and if not, what is it referred to as, if anything?

Such as:

> *Ch'out!*= combo of "watch out!" combined.
>
> *y'all* = you all
>
> *reckon* = do you think? Used: "You reckon she's ok?"

Comment: Perhaps [dialectal](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dialectal) English.

Comment: "Ch'out!" y'all, and reckon are far more broadly used than simply by "Hill-billies" - not at term you should really use as it is vague and somewhat disparaging."Y'all" is quite common throughout the Southern States and I, (BE speaker) might use "Ch'out!" and I do use "reckon".

Comment: As a hillbilly by upbringing, "ch'out" isn't anything I remember hearing, "y''all" is widespread southern US English, and "reckon" is perfectly standard general English.

Comment: "reckon" goes all the way back to Old English.  "Y'all" may be headed for being the standard second person plural form.

Comment: *Reckon* isn't slang, your example is standard usage of the word.

Comment: @nnnnnn That usage of *reckon* strikes me as distinctly American, though.

Comment: @TRIG - We use it that way all the time here in Australia, and I know British people who say it too.

Comment: Lol. Are these two contractions of English word and this other English word considered English?

Comment: This usage of "reckon" is marked "informal" in Oxford dictionaries, but it is common enough in British English.

Comment: @TRiG: New Zealanders use it too for that matter.

Comment: People are taking for granted that this is a "thing". None of those expressions are hillbilly. And even a northerner speaking fast will say watch out like that. And regardless of that, they are **not slang,** for pete's sake. You English speakers should go out into your gardens and eat worms!

Comment: Until I moved to Texas, having grown up in California, I had no idea how useful *y'all" is.  Now I can't imagine how to "translate" "y'all" into formal English, y'all know what I mean?

Comment: Y'all is used in two ways, depending on the area. It can be used as plural, or as a formal singular/plural.

Comment: Don't forget the word/phrase "All y'all" meaning roughly "I'm not just speaking to y'all, but to all y'all." What fun!

Answer (score 21):

The answer to the question "is it a type of English" is definitely "yes". While the lines between "language" and "dialect" and "local slang" can blur, it's obvious that certain geographical areas have their particular style of speech, and these local variants are certainly studied as regional and local dialects, and not (as some people might claim) as "mistakes" or errors in speech.

Here's a [good podcast episode](https://slate.com/podcasts/lexicon-valley/2019/08/john-mcwhorter-on-language-versus-dialect) by linguist John McWhorter about what constitutes a "dialect" vs a "language", if you want to learn more about what makes a "type of English".

And as for your specific dialect in question, "hillbilly" usually refers to residents of the Appalachian and Ozark mountains in the eastern USA, and they have a rich and quite distinct dialect with its distinct phonology and vocabulary. The Wikipedia entry for ["Appalachian English"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English) lists as references many books published on the topic, if you want to read up more on it.

Comment: I thought the major difference between a dialect and a language is that a language is a dialect with an army.

Comment: A language is a dialect with a good public relations firm.

Comment: @StianYttervik:  The original quote adds ["and a navy".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy)

Comment: I'd be more interested in book published in Appalachian than books about Appalachian :)

Answer (score 13):

I've voted up the "Appalachian English" answer, but depending on what you mean, there has historically been a larger sub-dialect area in the US referred to as "South Midland" with related or sub-dialects that include Appalachia and the Ozark highlands in Missouri<sup>*</sup>. It has often been ethnically associated with the in-migration of the [Scotts-Irish in America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch-Irish_Americans#American_settlement). There's a discussion of it on [Robert Delaney's website](http://robertspage.com/dialects.html). It can effectively be considered a "highlands" accent, which sounds more like standard Midlands the further from the rural hills you go.

[image]

A lot of South Midland isn't super noticeably different from the rest of Midland (which many consider "Standard American English"), except in a few details. Using "you all" for second person plural is my favorite, but linguists seem to prefer to talk about things like "cot-caught merger". However, in the Ozarks and Appalachia the difference is much more pronounced.

Second person plural map:
[image]
(Its a bit tough to see, but there's a lot of yellow "You all" in that whiteish in-between area)

Cot-Caught merger map:
[image]
Green is complete, yellow is in process.

Pen-pin merger map:
[image]
At first glance this looks "southern", but then you notice it extends well up into standard Midlands areas like Kansas City and Indianapolis as well.

For background, I grew up in Tulsa, OK, and have been often told I have "no accent". However, for me "caught" and "cot" are homonyms, as are "pin" and "pen", and the proper second person plural in English is "you all". These are just facts, and I cannot be convinced otherwise.

---

<sup>* - Current linguistic opinion is that this dialect has slowly become subsumed by "North" Midland, and they are today similar enough to not be considered separate dialects. However, there's still lots of older recorded media out there (not to mention older human beings) from when that wasn't the case.</sup>

Comment: I suspect that pin-pen circle in California is linguistic evidence of the Okie Dust Bowl migrations.

Comment: What is the place labeled "12" on the first map? Is it DC? And what name goes with "3"? I expect answers to those questions are on a web site from which you copied the map, but you haven't told us where to find that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - I didn't make the map, so you're not exactly asking the expert here. However, I suspect the "Pennsylvania German-English" label was meant to go with that 12 (Amish?) and the "New England Western" label with 3. You can go look at the maps in context at the website I linked. Who knows, the author might even respond to requests.

Answer (score 9):

I've seen it described as "Appalachian English" or the 'Appalachian Dialect'. (From Wikipedia):

> Appalachian English is a variant of American English native to the Appalachian mountain region of the Eastern United States.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English

[This article](https://www.csmonitor.com/USA/USA-Update/2015/0713/Stereotype-or-source-of-pride-Hillbilly-dialect-makes-comeback-in-Appalachia) specifically links 'Hillbillies' with Appalachian English

> After years of association with "The Beverly Hillbillies," Appalachian people are taking back their dialect.

Comment: The question uses expressions that are not hillybilly or Appalachian. They are southern and/southwestern, too.

Answer (score 2):

Could be called a **Patois** (*pat-wah*) which is speech or shared language that is considered "nonstandard" though this is not defined formally.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patois

It is not a Pidgin because that is a simplified crossover of two languages - the meeting of two circles in a Venn diagram.

It is also not a Creole, which is a stable natural language developed from a mixture of different languages.   If there are a good percentage of loan words from outside english, then perhaps this could fit.

The phrase **Dialect** would fit, but **Vernacular** is better because it has a strong geophysical connection.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernacular